# Why is an un-deletable Springboard app on my screen after the iOS 6 upgrade?

Tags: ipod-touch, springboard, ios

I just updated to iOS 6 and I have this springboard app that I cannot delete. I've tried restarting, and opening the app just ends up in it closing itself. Any advice?

By the way, I am using an iPod Touch 4 that has never been jailbroken.

[image]

Comment: Any history of jailbreaking this device?

Comment: @bmike Nope, I haven't.

Comment: Odd - the springboard process is supposed to run without an icon on the home screen. If you have a good backup, I would erase all content and settings and then use the device without restoring your backup to make sure you have a good build. If so, then you could erase all content and settings again and restore from your backup.

Comment: I have this issue with a device that has indeed been jailbroken, but restored to normal a long time ago (2+ years). Puzzled!

Comment: @bmike If I make a backup now, do you think it would still be backed up?

Comment: Yes - the springboard data is backed up (it records where each app is positioned). You also could try connecting it to iTunes and re-ordering things. Can you even bury that app inside a folder?

Comment: I can. After I erased everything, the app was not there, but when I restored, it came back with another app (ShareE or something similar), so I am gonna download the update again on my computer and restore, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: That’s a nice background! Where did you get it from? Also, applying the restore from iTunes will fix this. I just tested. I was getting “iAdOptOut”, “SpringBoard”, and “Diagnostics” on my home screen.

Comment: Just applied the restore and the apps are back - SpringBoard and SharedPackageE. Any other suggestions? :/

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix your problem without Jailbreaking (you would just kill the Springboard process, and then it would restart with those icons removed). It's weird to see that Springboard now has a .app in `/Applications` now. Interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going through a hard reset, it might be worth doing a soft reset.

To do that, press the Power & Home buttons simultaneously until the iPod shuts down by itself. Release the buttons and power it back on.

This might take care of the issue. Otherwise, just restore it using iTunes and if you have no valuable data to lose, choose the "Setup Up As New Phone" option.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't a big enough issue for me to reset my whole device. It's just two little apps that I could hide away in a folder if I can't find any other way to get rid of them.